# Stopping Tab View from Restore to full screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I had changed the view size of TabViewController on application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. And it is working as expected. But my problem is when I show a view using modelViewController then tabViewController view restore to full screen. How can I make tab view not to restore back to full screen.

```
 [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Could you attach screenshots of what you are currently seeing and what is going wrong and/or what you would like to do?

Comment: added a screen shot. please check it now

Comment: Wow. That's crazy! How are you presenting and then dismissing your modal view?  Copy that code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be better off if you move your tabViewController-shrinking-code into `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` (tabViewControllers methods). Dont't forget to call `[super ...]` when overriding this methods.

Also make sure to set `tabViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout` to `NO`.

Comment: when i add code in viewWillAppear it does not allow screen to scale to full screen but origin of the screen moves to top left corner. When i add code to viewDidAppear then it appear at correct place after some time which is not good effect. can you guide me how to fix this?

Comment: i user this code to in viewWillAppear. [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] performSelector:@selector(designTabView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];